# VS Code built in debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have been very successful debugging JavaScript with the Chrome debugger extension in VS Code. But now that this extension is deprecated in favor of using the VS Code's built in debugger, I cannot seem to figure out how to get it working. localhost:8080 in the launch.json is not going to work for me because I set a dev domain in my host file to machine's IP address on port 443. I tried using my configuration with Live Server, but my breakpoints don't get hit.

```
"configurations": [
  {
    "type": "pwa-chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
  }
]
```

I need this configuration, or at least the url, to work with VS Code debugger.

```
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Chrome Launch",
    "type": "pwa-chrome",           
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "https://devman.com/",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "userDataDir": false,
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "runtimeArgs": [
       "--profile-directory=debug-profile-devman"
    ]            
  }
]
```